# Will a left cornered viewfinder be difficult to use for a left eye dominant person?

Tags: viewfinder, eyes, handling

I am thinking of purchasing a [Sony alpha 6000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=13&v=qzTwXGO9Km4) which has a viewfinder on the left corner. Given that I am left eye dominant and so would use my left eye to look through the viewfinder, will this be a massive inconvenience? I.e will this be very awkward and uncomfortable? Perhaps I won't be able to put the camera in the appropriate position because my nose will get in the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comfort is obviously a subjective quality and can't really be answered objectively.

My gut says, it won't make a difference. I just held my two cameras to my left eye and it felt awkward, likely because I on't think I have ever done this before. But, nothing with my hand positions had to change to accommodate the switch of eyes.

Even quickly doing some searches, I think we have consensus:

[Another similar question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89656/camera-handling-right-handed-left-eye-dominant)

[And a rabbit hole perhaps](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4111936)

As with all things camera and gear related though, I'd say hit your nearest camera show and hold the camera (or its closest on display model), if it feels OK there it will work. And take the time to hold some competitors too. If another camera feels even better, go with that.

Comment: Thanks! I also found those google hits when searching, however I think my question is a little more nuanced as i regards viewfinders that are placed in the left corner.

Comment: @simonthethird I think it's worth noting that the second link mentions Sony and the a6000 but also according to that a poll was roughly half the users were left eye dominant. I somehow doubt if that's true Sony or anywould would not have noticed and worked out the ergonomics. Still, I wouldn't trust any internet source to tell me what I would find comfortable

Answer (score 1):

I’m left eye dominant as well. I have a centered viewfinder where eye doesn’t matter, but I still use my right eye for the viewfinder. In fact, I find it easier to look what is happening around me with my left eye. Keeping both eyes open has advantages: [How can one learn to shoot with both eyes open, and what are the advantages?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8780/71147)

Comment: That's really interesting. Is there a specific type of photography where it's useful to monitor what is happening around you with your left eye? Also, do you not feel that your automatically at a disadvantage because if you don't use your dominant eye for the viewfinder? Thanks!

Comment: @simonthethird I do exactly the same. Fireworks, motorsport events, stage shows... anywhere that there is action not visible within the camera's field of view.

Comment: @simonthethird I recommend reading the question and the answers I linked to see the advantages of shooting with both eyes open. It takes some getting used to, but as a mainly street- and eventphotographer, I think it's very useful. I do not feel at a disadvantage for using my non-dominant eye. After a bit of practice, I can see both the 'real' world and the 'photo' world at the same time in my mind and it doesn't matter which eye sees which. I do have a digital viewfinder, which may potentially make separating the images in my mind easier. I have no experience with optical viewfinders.